# How to select part from money in Database using sql

Tags: mysql

Please which query can i use to select for example if the user has **10,500** as his Salary and i want him only to be able to withdraw 10,000 while database keeps the remaining balance.  I only want the user to collect money in Domination of **1000**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mod function to check if the denomination is in 1000s for example

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select emp_no,salary, salary % 1000 modsalary from employees;
+--------+--------+-----------+
| emp_no | salary | modsalary |
+--------+--------+-----------+
|      1 |  20000 |         0 |
|      2 |  39500 |       500 |
|      3 |  50000 |         0 |
|      4 |  19500 |       500 |
|      5 |  10000 |         0 |
|      6 |  19500 |       500 |
|      7 |  40000 |         0 |
|      9 |   NULL |      NULL |
+--------+--------+-----------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And trap errors in a trigger for example

```
drop trigger if exists wdl;

delimiter $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `wdl` before INSERT ON `employees_wdl` FOR EACH 
ROW BEGIN
 declare verr int;
 declare vsalary int;
 set verr = 0;

 if not exists(select 1 from employees where emp_no = new.emp_no) then
     set verr = 1;
 else
    select salary into vsalary from employees  where emp_no = new.emp_no;
    if new.amt > vsalary then set verr = 1; end if;
    if new.amt % 1000 <> 0 then set verr = 1 ; end if;
 end if;
 if verr <> 0 then
    signal sqlstate '45000'
        set message_text = 'Wdl amt incorrect or no employee exists';    
 end if;
END $$
delimiter ;
```

Result

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> truncate table employees_wdl;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.22 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into employees_wdl values (2,40000);
ERROR 1644 (45000): Wdl amt incorrect or no employee exists
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into employees_wdl values (2,35000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into employees_wdl values (2,35200);
ERROR 1644 (45000): Wdl amt incorrect or no employee exists
```

Comment: Please i. Don't understand this at all,  how do i apply it in php please

Comment: Dunno, If its a php problem you should tag as such. I will delete in 10